# How to filter JSON objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have to filter JSON by parameters.

Get method : http://localhost:5000/api/car?bodyTypeId=2 (I need to get JSON objects only with bodyTypeId = 2. But unfortunately i getting them all):

```
[
    {
         "id": 1,
         "bodyTypeId": 1,  //bodyTypeId not equal to 2
         "carManufacturerId": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "bodyTypeId": 2,
        "carManufacturerId": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "bodyTypeId": 2,
        "carManufacturerId": 1
    }
]
```

Controller:

```
async getAll(req, res){  //filter
        let {carManufacturerId, bodyTypeId} = req.body
        let cars;
        if (!carManufacturerId && !bodyTypeId){
            cars = await Car.findAll()
        }
        if (carManufacturerId && !bodyTypeId){
            cars = await Car.findAll({where: {carManufacturerId}})
        }
        if (!carManufacturerId && bodyTypeId){
            cars = await Car.findAll({where: {bodyTypeId}})
        }
        if (carManufacturerId && bodyTypeId){
            cars = await Car.findAll({where: {bodyTypeId,carManufacturerId}})
        }
        return res.json(cars)
    }
```

Router:

```
router.get('/', CarController.getAll)
```

Comment: what is Car in your controller

Answer (score 0):

> Your data is an array so you can use filter method.
> check here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp

```
const data = [
    {
         "id": 1,
         "bodyTypeId": 1,  
         "carManufacturerId": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "bodyTypeId": 2,
        "carManufacturerId": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "bodyTypeId": 2,
        "carManufacturerId": 1
    }
]

let result = null
data.filter(json => {
    if(json.bodyTypeId = 2) {
      result = json
    }
})

return result
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to filter from an array of objects you can use the `Array.filter` method.

```js
const allCars = [
    {
         "id": 1,
         "bodyTypeId": 1,  
         "carManufacturerId": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "bodyTypeId": 2,
        "carManufacturerId": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "bodyTypeId": 2,
        "carManufacturerId": 1
    }
]

const result = allCars.filter(car => car.bodyTypeId == bodyTypeId);
```